# how to send metrics/ diagnostics logs of azure cosmos db to azure log analytics?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, log-analysis

I used Azure Cosmos DB right now, but I want to send diagnostics logs or metrics of cosmos db to log analytics.

I searched in google from two days onwards but there is no related information for that. Can you please tell me how to send metrics/ diagnostics logs of azure cosmos db to azure log analytics?

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't possible back in July, but you can now connect Azure Cosmos DB to Log Analytics using the Azure portal, CLI, or Powershell. Instructions are available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/logging.